# Google app engine RAM not increasing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

so i was receiving this error:

Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 138 MB after servicing 200 requests total

So i upgraded my tier in app.yaml:

```
instance_class: B4_1G
basic_scaling:
max_instances: 25 
idle_timeout: 10m
```

after deploying I should be getting 512 MB of RAM but I still get the same error as above. Is there a lag until the RAM kicks in or do I have to do something else besides change the app.yaml file?

Comment: You may have old instances running w/the previous config -- make sure you stop all of them from the admin console and that the default version is set to your latest one!

Comment: @AlexMartelli i think you're onto something. So in my app.yaml I change the version to 2 (was previously 1). I go to app engine settings and shut down version 1. So now I can see version 2 in the list and see activity on it. But for some reason app engine keeps creating instance version 1 and its showing activity on both versions now? Don't know why? Version 1 doesn't exist anymore so why is it recreating/using it!??

Comment: @AlexMartelli if its helps it says "Version 1 (default)" whatever that means where Version 2 does not have default after it

Comment: version 1 still exists, archived on the servers, and instances of it keep getting created because it's still the default version.  Change the default version e.g from the google developers console: console.developers.google.com, pick yr project, compute, app engine, versions.

Comment: @AlexMartelli fixed, thank you! If you make all of this into an answer I can accept and up vote :)

Comment: Done, I put the advice that was in my comments into a single answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be: old instances running w/the previous config -- the solution is to stop all of them from the admin console and that the default version is set to the latest one.

Just pushing a new version is not sufficient.  The older version still exists, archived on the servers, and instances of it keep getting created because it's still the **default** version.

To change the default version, e.g, from the google developers console: log in to console.cloud.google.com, pick your project, then, from the menu on the top left, compute, app engine, versions.